# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT Google Maps API after working fine

Tags: google-maps-api-3

[I am using the BIOMASS Codeigniter library, but I don't think this is causing a problem]

I am using the Google Maps API with an API key. Everything was working perfectly all yesterday. Came in this morning, tried it out (with about 100 requests) and everything was fine. My boss tried the same exact thing right after, and he got OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error (same IP address). Since then, all I get is this OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.

In the meantime, since Google is changing it's usage policy, I purchased access with a new API key.  Tried with the new API key - same error. Then, I changed the API key to XXXXX. Same OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error! I know that I am definitely using the invalid API key, since I display it on the error. I've cleared cache, but no change.

Is it possible that our IP address is being blocked until midnight? Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: How are you querying the API?  How are you including the key (sounds like it isn't correct)?

Answer (score 0):

@geocodezip - [sorry this is an 'answer' - I don't have the level to 'comment'] In the evening, it was working fine, and I could see the traffic on the dashboard. So, not sure why this was happening. Maybe it needed time to cycle the $ funding?